# How do I do polymorphism in a loop with StringTemplate?

Tags: polymorphism, stringtemplate

Let's say my model has an array of class `IAnimal` which I want to render using a template.

Each implementation of `IAnimal` has its own template (`.st` file) and this list is rendered within another generic template.

```
generic(e)::= <<
    List of animals : 
    $e.Animals:{ a | $renderAnimal(a)$} 
>>
```

I understand that I can use an `import` statement to override `renderAnimal` but then it will use this override for all the animals, no matter their type.

I could not find an example in the [documentation about inheritance](https://github.com/antlr/stringtemplate4/blob/master/doc/inheritance.md)

How can I make my generic template use a different template for each item of `e.Animals` depending on its type ?